# C# Regular Expression throws Unterminated [] set

Tags: c#, regex

Expression:
    `<!--[^]+-->`

Content:

```
Hello <!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--> world!
```

C# code:

```
Regex clearMarkup = new Regex(@"\<!--\[\^]\+-->");
clearMarkup.Replace(str, ""); // str is the content as shown above.
```

Expected output:

```
Hello world!
```

The Regular expression created in http://www.regextester.com/ is working properly, however, in C# it throws error as:

```
Unterminated [] set
```

I got the same error in http://regexstorm.net/tester which is .Net RegEx tester.

I tried with: 
    `\<!--\[\^]\+-->` and the issue got resolved, however, it does not match any of the contents.

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: what do you want to do with that regex? better also paste corresponding expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is twofold.  You need to use a RegexOption and assign the string back to str.

The RegexOptions.Singleline makes regex treat everything as if it is on one line and ignores the \n.

You also need to assign the returned string from clearMarkup.Replace to your original variable:

```
str = clearMarkup.Replace(str, "");
```

Here is a link to a working example: [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sleK3w)

```
    string str = @"Hello <!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
                        o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
                        w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
                        .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
                        </style><![endif]--> world!";



Regex clearMarkup = new Regex(@"(<!--\[.*\]-->)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
str = clearMarkup.Replace(str, ""); // str is the content as shown above.       

str.Dump();
```

Comment: That does the job! RegexOptions.Singleline was the prime missing piece. About the 2nd issue “assign the returned string”, I was bit lazy to write that in question, however, I have that in my code. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets in a regex indicate the a character group which matches any character between the brackets.

The caret character ^ at the beginning of a character group [] has a special meaning and says "not what follows", so [^abc] matches any character EXCEPT a, b, or c.

In your expression:

[ indicates the start of a character group

^] indicates anything except a right bracket - you want to match anything EXCEPT a right bracket and there's no right bracket to match the left bracket.  The ^] go together and there is no right bracket left to match the left bracket. So it complains.  Maybe what you meant is this:

```
<--\[.*\]-->
```

Which matches any string that starts with

```
<--[
```

And ends with|

```
]-->
```

Without knowing what you want to match it's impossible to say.
This is a useful tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: I get your point, but replacing with .* is also not helping. Apparently, [^]+ does the job. But only issue is with C#.

Comment: Arguing with C# is a losing strategy and without knowing what you want to match I cannot be more specific.  The caret, when it appears after the beginning of a character group, is a special character that changes the meaning of what follows.

This explains in more detail the meaning of the characters: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Appreciate your time.